# How to share a part of memory using mmap

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I have 3 tools and I need them to share the same first 4096 bytes of their own memory.
Each tool can increase their memory independently.

So a resume:

tool1:

0 - 4096 :shared between 1,2,3

4097 - 8192 : internal to 1

tool2:

0 - 4096 :shared between 1,2,3

4097 - 16384 : internal to 2

tool3:

0 - 4096 :shared between 1,2,3

4097 - 12288 : internal to 3

Is it possible to use mmap to achieve my goal because I prefer mmap ?
If another solution is available, maybe I could adapt my code.

Thank you in  advance for your help.

Comment: _I need them to share the same first 4096 bytes of their own memory_ What do you mean by "their own memory"? I assume you mean something like heap memory because the _first_ 4096 bytes of a process is address 0x00000000 and that page is read/write protected. When you use `mmap`, you can get a pointer to an area that is shared amongst your programs. But, the specific address shouldn't be a concern. If it is, _why_? You should post your code in the question and ask a [more] specific question about its operation.

Comment: I mean 0 is the start of a kind of linear memory in each tool. So, 0 is the starting pointer used by each memory tool.

Comment: What do you mean by "a kind of linear memory"? Within a process, _all_ memory is linear. I think you're close to an XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem So, forget `mmap` et. al. for the moment and describe _what_ you want to achieve. (e.g.) "I am writing programs that need to share student data" What is your _need_? `mmap` is a _solution_ to a need.

Answer (score 1):

There are serious security and maintainability issues with mapping and using the first page of virtual memory, but you can do it if you really want.

First you need to adjust a sysctl that prevents you from doing things like this (for good reason):

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.mmap_min_addr=0
```

Then use `mmap` as you normally would for shared memory, but with `MAP_FIXED`. Now you can read and write to the first page (including the NULL pointer):

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int fd = shm_open("silly_example", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
        mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
        ftruncate(fd, 4096);
        int *ptr = (int*) 0;
        *ptr = 123;
        printf("%d\n", *ptr);
        getchar();
}
```

You can verify that the mapped is created:

```
$ cat /proc/17444/maps
00000000-00001000 rw-s 00000000 00:12 41774576                           /dev/shm/silly_example
```

All processes mapping the shared file in this way will share the 4096 bytes of memory (mapped to the zero-page). I used POSIX shared memory in this example, but you can use any file as long as you truncate it to 4096 bytes.

You should seriously consider what you are trying to do, and if this is really necessary.

Comment: I mean 0 is the start of a kind of linear memory in each tool. So, 0 is the starting pointer used by each memory tool. But how the first 4096 bytes are shared and how can I internally protect added memory from being accessed by the 2 other tools.

Comment: The NULL pointer is a constant zero value in the program; it is distinguishable from a variable address that just happens to be zero. Malloc, fopen, etc should never return a zero, since that would compare equal to their NULL error return. However, there's no reason &x could not be zero.

Comment: @Alphapage: I'm not sure I understand your question. By running the code above in all three processes, the first 4096 bytes of memory will be shared between them, but all other memory will not be shared. You can MAP_ANON | MAP_FIXED the other memory in each process and it will only be accessible internally. By default in linux, memory is *not* shared between processes